# AngularJS: Advice on architecture for changing DOM based on AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, angularjs

Angular's website has this simple example:

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}
```

However I'd to perform something more complex than this, and I'm not sure how, even after reading through lots of Angular's docs. I need to perform some DOM manipulations based on the result of the ajax request. How should I go about structuring this code? Angular's website specifically says:

> Do not use controllers for: Any kind of DOM manipulation — Controllers
>   should contain only business logic.

Okay... so where should I handle DOM manipulation based on the ajax return data? I realize their docs say this:

> If you have to perform your own manual DOM manipulation, encapsulate
>   the presentation logic in directives.

But I am just uncertain as to how to glue this all together properly. How would I put this all together, and do it in a way such that if the AJAX request is made again, and the "model" changes, the corresponding logic is still executed to perform DOM manipulation?

Basically I am asking, if not in the controller, where would you perform DOM manipulation based on an AJAX request?

Comment: Give us an example and I would love to help you figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure how to other than textually, since I'm not sure how to write the code for this.

1. Perform ajax request.
2. Update DOM based on results of ajax request.
3. If ajax request is made again, make sure the same view logic in 2. is again executed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the downvote is for. There are lots of questions similar to this here on SO where people are asking for architecture based on a description of the problem.

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted. So do you actually want to change DOM elements, or just bind textual data from your ajax to the text of an element?

Comment: I am looking to actually perform conditional DOM manipulation logic based on the ajax result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing an AJAX request with $http or $resource, you will inject the result of this AJAX request in the $scope of your controller.

With a directive you can $watch when your model change ... So yes do it with a directive it's the right way !

For example the HTML part :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>Usage Directive for model data change</h1>
    <div>
      <input directive type="text" ng-model="example"/>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The scripts part with a simple controller and a directive :

```
angular.module('App', []).controller('MyController', function($scope){

    // In real prod app you'll use the $http API to get the data from the server
    $scope.example = "Example data";
  });

angular.module('App').directive('directive', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue){
        console.log(newValue);
      })
    }
  }
});
```

If you run this code and you open your browser console (F12) and you change the input value you will see that we get the new value with the directive and the $watch function on your scope.

Comment: A piece of code for ? the $resource factory, the controller and the view with the directive ?